# Stop browser.downloads.download force-encoding file names

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a browser addon and I'm debugging it in Firefox 56.

There seems to be a bug in `browser.downloads.download` which causes files downloaded like this:

```
browser.downloads.download({url:'https://foo.bar/example - foobar.mp3'})
```

to be named like this:

```
example%20-%20foobar.mp3
```

Is that expected behavior? When I manually enter the url and press enter to download it or when I create a link with that url and click it, this does not happen. I already tried using decodeURI() on the url before calling the download function, but it is still adding the encoding.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try setting the [filename property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download#parameters) on the options argument. Since the default filename is the path of the url, or whatever the appropriate header is set to, (which will end up url encoded) it is just saving as that without decoding the entities.

Comment: But what if the server suggest a better filename in the content-disposition header?

Comment: I believe the filename property would override it, but if there is a filename provided in the header you probably wouldn't get a url encoded filename. So you would have to weight your options and decided what would be best for your use cases